# EncryptedSharedPreferences result in UnrecoverableKeyException

Tags: android, androidx, android-keystore, androidx-security

I'm using the new `EncryptedSharedPreferences` class in a way recommended from Google:

```
private fun securePrefs(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    val fileName = "sharedPrefsSecure"
    val masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)
    return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(fileName, masterKeyAlias, context,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV, EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM)
}
```

However, the app crashed on emulator (Pixel 2 API 26) on the next day. This happens every time I start the app, until I fully uninstall it and reinstall again (from Studio with Run) - then it works fine. However, once I restart the emulator, it starts to crash again until full reinstall. My Samsung was fine, even after restart. I wonder if I will also get something similar on real devices.

Here is the crash stack trace:

```
2020-02-24 17:42:52.632 12398-12398/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 12398
    java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Failed to obtain information about key
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreSecretKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:282)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineGetKey(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:98)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1062)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.<init>(AndroidKeystoreAesGcm.java:48)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getAead(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:111)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getOrGenerateNewAeadKey(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:130)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.<init>(AndroidKeysetManager.java:118)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager.<init>(AndroidKeysetManager.java:88)
        at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.build(AndroidKeysetManager.java:185)
        at androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(EncryptedSharedPreferences.java:123)
        at com.myapp.base.service.DefaultKeystoreService.securePrefs(DefaultKeystoreService.kt:43)
        at com.myapp.base.service.DefaultKeystoreService.sharedPrefsForKey(DefaultKeystoreService.kt:37)
        at com.myapp.base.service.DefaultKeystoreService.get(DefaultKeystoreService.kt:17)
        at com.myapp.base.repository.DefaultCredentialsRepository.getRefreshToken(DefaultCredentialsRepository.kt:78)
        at com.myapp.base.repository.DefaultCredentialsRepository.getCredentials(DefaultCredentialsRepository.kt:20)
        at com.myapp.base.repository.DefaultCredentialsRepository.runAuthFlowWithTokens(DefaultCredentialsRepository.kt:28)
        at com.myapp.main.AppRootModel$startAuthFlow$1.invokeSuspend(AppRootModel.kt:43)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:313)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:54)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.myapp.main.AppRootModel.startAuthFlow(AppRootModel.kt:39)
        at com.myapp.main.AppRootModel.<init>(AppRootModel.kt:33)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.myapp.main.AppRootFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.myapp.main.AppRootFragment.onCreateView(AppRootFragment.kt:25)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
2020-02-24 17:42:52.633 12398-12398/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid key blob
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:695)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreProvider.loadAndroidKeyStoreSecretKeyFromKeystore(AndroidKeyStoreProvider.java:283)
            ... 69 more
```

Comment: Seems like other people are also having this problem. Here is a bug opened - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147480931